# Remove only one item from unordered_multiset

Tags: c++, stl, set, erase, unordered-multiset

I want to erase a specific element from `std::unordered_multiset`, but when I try with `erase` function, it eliminates all the items, no matter how many they are.
For example:

```
std::unordered_multiset<int> M;
M.insert(1);
M.insert(1);
M.insert(1);
std::cout<<M.count(1)<<std::endl;

M.erase(1);
std::cout << M.count(1) << std::endl;
```

I expect this to print 3 then 2. But it prints 3 then 0. So how to remove only one item?

Comment: You surely meant "print 3, then 2"?

Comment: Have you tried it??? There is nothing to do with remove-erase idiom!! @Ron

Comment: Sorry, my bad @BartekBanachewicz. Edited

Comment: Which _one item_ is that? They all have the same value. There is no first nor last element in an unordered multiset.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use another `erase` overload:

```
std::unordered_multiset<int> s { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 };

const auto it = s.find(2);

if (it != s.end())
    s.erase(it);
```

[**Live version**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aea94a559d8e4ad6)

Comment: Why range when there is a version that accepts one iterator?

Comment: @Slava Range version is useful if you want to remove multiple ones, of course.

Comment: Your first and second version requires check, as it is illegal to pass `end()` to `erase()` and `next()`